# why collision not detection not happened in Two Sphere

Tags: opengl, collision-detection, projectile-physics

I start practice 3d collision detection of sphere in OpenGl containing two sphere one sphere hit using cannon gun but collision not detect when it hit and when i debug code collision statement triger when sphere is too far of each other here is sphere One code

```
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(400, 50, -400);
    drawBomb();
    glPopMatrix();
```

Connon gun code is here which control by keyboard handler

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(600, 0, -400);
    glRotatef(-longFire, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(-longFireChaw, 0, 1, 0);

    //glTranslatef(0, 0, -25);
    drawFireHolder();
    //printf_s("Long fire is %d", longFire);

    glPopMatrix();
```

second sphere code is here which hit by mouse handler

```
glPushMatrix();
 // bombX is global variable of value 600
 // bombY and bombZ is global variable of value 0
    glTranslatef(bombX, bombY, -400);
    //glRotatef(-longFire, xRotate, yRotate, zRotate);
    glRotatef(-longFire, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(-longFireChaw, 0, 1, 0);
    //glRotatef(longFire, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, bombZ);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 25);
    drawBomb();
    glPopMatrix();
```

Timer and Shphere collsion detection code s here

```
dx = 400 - bombX;  // 400 for sphere one x and bombX for sphere two
        dy = 50-bombY;  //50 for sphere one y and bombY for sphere two
        dz = -400 -(-400);// 50 for sphere one z and bombz for sphere two

        float distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);

        if (distance <=6+6) // 6 is radius of first and second sphere
        {
            printf("Collision Occur");
        }

        bombX-=1;

        bombY =0.3+bombY*sin((longFire*3.1424543567) / 180);
        bombZ++;
        //printf("Y IS %f",bombY);
```

Keyboard Handler  code is here

```
if (key == 't' || key == 'T')
    {
        xRotate = 1, yRotate = 0, zRotate = 0;
        longFire += 5;
        handlerMove();
    }
    if (key == 'e' || key == 'E')
    {
        xRotate = 1, yRotate = 0, zRotate = 0;
        longFire -= 5;
        handlerMove();
    }
    if (key == 'r' || key == 'R')
    {
        xRotate = 0, yRotate = 1, zRotate = 0;
        longFireChaw += 5;
        handlerMove();
    }
    if (key == 'w' || key == 'W')
    {
        xRotate = 0, yRotate = 1, zRotate = 0;
        longFireChaw -= 5;
        handlerMove();
    }
```

Comment: You tagged this with "bullet-physics", but in the code you aren't using it. Are you intending to write your own collision detection? If yes please remove the tag

Comment: @UnholySheep ok i remove tag it is pleasure if you give answer to this question ?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your collision detection code (except for some inefficiencies, but those should not be related) - but are you sure your collision coordinates are the same as the visual representation?

Comment: yes coordinates are same when i used bombY increament only 0.3 and not used any angle it work but when i used gun which usually contain some angle collision not work ..

Comment: The reason I suspect it to be a visual issue is because you are applying your transformations in the "wrong" order - it should be Rotate - Scale - Translate to avoid most issues

Comment: When you are learning you should consider using Modern OpenGL instead of the fixed function pipeline.